# How to add async validation in FormBuilder.group?

Tags: angular

I have validation rule for FormBuilder way:

```
this.recoveryForm = this.fb.group({
      'phone': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.phoneValidator]],
      'confirmation_code': [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(5)]
    });
```

How to add async validation for phone number using http request to server?
Is it possible in `FormBuilder` or exists another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing your async validator to the synchronous validators array, I think the way it should be is this:

```
...
email: ['', [Validators.required], [ValidationService.phoneValidator]],
```

Comment: Can you share phoneValidator as http request?

Comment: it;s a different question all together i guess you can check this [link](https://kahlillechelt.com/asynchronous-validation-with-angular-reactive-forms-1a392971c062) for info